# Players who want to duel each other

Tags: dnd-4e, player-vs-player

I know 4e doesn't have rules for it nor is really designed for this to happen, but does anyone know of a good way to handle PCs that would like to duel, during our downtime between story arcs?

Also, if possible, could anyone suggest a map that would be a balance between both melee and range combat styles?

Answer (score 6):

If the combat is played for story reasons only and the character aren't actually willing to see which build wins over which, you could treat the face-off as a skill encounter.

This way, most characters would be able to participate without the need to find a seemingly impossible balance between roles and ranges.

Comment: I believe the players would like it to be actual combat

Comment: @Kamina This is the wrong game system to satisfy their desires, then.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Maybe do a "Suddenly, 3.5!" would work? xD

Comment: @LucasFamelli I'd rather have a "Suddenly, some actually working and balanced PvP system". But this means having separate character sheets and not quite the point of pitching my build against yours.

Comment: @Zachiel "Suddenly, Fate Accelerated!" Yeah, not quite the same as the existing build. ^^

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there are any rules that prevent them from fighting each other. It's probably safer if they agree to terms like "fight until first bloodied" or "fight until zero hp" rather than "fight to the death". As for the actual fight, I imagine it would rather boring and unsatisfying, since the game revolves around synergistic powers across party roles rather than a lone character fighting.

If they're just sparring, I would make them design the map together—this is their characters finding and agreeing on a sparring space. I would also just use an ability check vs ability check, using the modifier associated with their class's attack powers. Actually doing an entire fight is a waste of time for the group; if they want to spar, let them do it on their own time.

Comment: While there are no ruels that prevent sparring, the classes are not balanced for pvp or 1on1.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good idea. Presumably the players will figure this out right quick.

Comment: This!  Either they both list their preferred battleground traits, or they hire a proxy with a list of qualifications (as in, they both tell the proxy/dm their requests/requirements and then you make a suitable arena).

Answer (score 3):

While there is nothing in the rules against PVP in D&D 4e, but it is very inadvisable. There is absolutely no balancing between the roles and classes in 4e for PVP and one player will probably end up extremely frustrated by the whole occurrence. 4e's design and balance are completely structured around players vs. monster.

Answer (score 3):

Let them duel.  Let the coin flip for who picks the arena.  First one to drop to zero HP loses.  It isn't balanced, but so what.  Make sure they know that it isn't balanced and the story is more important than the fairness.